# Como repetir uma chamada de uma função de a cada X segundos em PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação em Pyqt4 onde eu preciso carregar os dados para uma tabela vindo de um Webservice. Isso eu consegui fazer tranquilamente. Porém, agora, preciso que a cada 1 minuto, esses dados sejam atualizados.

Como eu posso fazer uma repetição de uma chamada de uma função a cada X segundos em PyQt4?

Existe algo específico para isso em Pyqt? (algo parecido com o setInterval do Javascript)

<sub>**Nota**: O processo recarregamento dos dados nesse intervalo tem que ser assíncrono</sub>

Comment: Não tenho PyQt instalado, por isso nem vou me arriscar a responder. Mas o caminho é usar o `QTimer`. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362340/pyqt4-creating-a-timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se usar o `QTimer` do [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Na documentação do PyQt4 não encontrei exemplos, mas acredito que deve ficar assim (a cada 1 segundo):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

def chamar():
    print 'Foo'

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(chamar)
timer.start(1000)
```

Todavia acredito que seja melhor usar `singleShot`, pois assim se uma função demorar mais que o timeout não haverá a chance dela ser executada duas ou mais simultaneamente (o que pode causar conflitos e "travamentos"), acredito que fique assim:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

def chamar():
    # Aqui fica o código que será executado

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setSingleShot(True)
    timer.timeout.connect(chamar)
    timer.start(1000)

chamar()
```

Comment: Realmente, a última opção é a melhor escolha. Em se tratando de requisições http, que pode travar um pouco mais que deveria, sempre é bom chamar a função novamente apenas se  a resposta for OK.